# Typical Linker error: Undefined reference to CV methods in c++

Tags: linker, cmake, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile and build a project which uses ROS and OpenCV libraries together. I have my .cpp files in src folder, and .h files in include folder.

Here is the CMakeLists.txt file that I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(uwsim_imgproc)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  image_transport
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES uwsim_imgproc filters
CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  include
)

link_directories( 
  ${OpenCV_LINK_DIRS}
)

add_library(filters
        src/Obstacle.cpp
        src/HorizonDetector.cpp
        src/GenericTools.cpp
        src/Kalman.cpp
        src/HungarianAlg.cpp
        src/Ctracker.cpp
)

add_executable(cameraSubscriber src/main.cpp)

add_dependencies(cameraSubscriber ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(cameraSubscriber
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
   filters
 )
```

And when I initiate catkin_make, which runs make internally, I get this error:

```
lib/libfilters.so: undefined reference to `cv::KalmanFilter::predict(cv::Mat const&)'
lib/libfilters.so: undefined reference to `cv::KalmanFilter::correct(cv::Mat const&)'
lib/libfilters.so: undefined reference to `cv::KalmanFilter::KalmanFilter(int, int, int, int)'
lib/libfilters.so: undefined reference to `cv::groupRectangles(std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, int, double)'
```

I look at the similar questions but the provided solutions did not for work me.

Any idea?

Comment: If `filters` library uses OpenCV, it should be linked with it. But you only link `cameraSubscriber` target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do you mean `target_link_libraries` part? I have `filters` there. Where exactly should I place `filters`?

Comment: I mean `target_link_libraries(filters  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`. In current version, you link `cameraSubscriber` with `filters` and OpenCV, but `filters` itself doesn't know about OpenCV libraries.

Comment: Oh! I just linkled as `target_link_libraries(filters
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}` and ta-da :) Thanks, you can add your solution as answer, as it worked, I can accept it!
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error output shows, `filters` library uses symbols from OpenCV library, but isn't linked with it. Your CMakeLists.txt should do this:

```
target_link_libraries(filters ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```